# Android launch configuration

Tags: android, android-widget

When I run the widget application I have an error like that:

> Launch configuration CharUtilsPerfRun references non-existing project
>   BioInfo.

What can I do for it? Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your project.

Click on Build Path >> Configure Build Path.

Go in Java Build Path >> Projects.

Remove any unrelated projects from there.

Then clean + Build your project and run it.